# save txt file in directory from csv python

Tags: python, csv

I am wondering how can I save a txt file into a directory which is shown in a CSV file.

The data I have is the following:

1. CSV file:

```
                                     name      type
0           aceyte_de_almendras_sin_fuego    varios
1                        aceyte_de_huevos    varios
2                    adobos_4e_solomillos  fiambres
3                  agraz_para_todo_el_año    varios
4                           aguja_paladar  pescados
```

2. Directories created according the CSV file (column 2)

```
varios
fiabre
pescados
```

3. txt files (column 1)

```
aceyte_de_almendras_sin_fuego.txt
aceyte_de_huevos.txt
adobos_4e_solomillos.txt
agraz_para_todo_el_año.txt
aguja_paladar.txt
```

I want now to save the txt files (3) in the existing directories (2) according the CSV file (1) and am not able even to write code that changes the directory.
The directories as well as the txt files are in the same directory: path

```
path = r'/home/datasci/prog_datasci_2/activities/activity_2'
for name, tipo in csv_document:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(path,name), os.path.join(path, tipo))
```

How would you do it?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `shutil.move` with `print` then perhaps you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, my code is totally wrong and I don't know even how to start. This is the way I started, but obviusly, is wrong.